# Question on 2-D Convolution

Tags: homework, convolution

This was a question on one of my past year paper questions.

> **Question:**  Prove
>
> $$f(m,n)*g(m-r,n-s) = f(m-r,n-s) *g(m,n)$$
>
> where $f(m,n)$ and $g(m,n)$ are 2-D discrete functions, $r$ and $s$
>   are integers and $*$ is the 2-D convolution operator.

Not sure how to start on this and need some guidance on it.

Comment: Hint:  Your mission, if you choose to accept it, is to try to do a one-dimensional case first.  Write the sum to compute the first convolution at $k$, and play with the index of summation $i$ (doing things like introducing a new variable $\ell = k - i$ or $k-i-r$ or something similar -- be creative) to see if you can rearrange things to get the second convolution sum.  Then become bolder.  Write the $2$-D sum and make two similar changes on the two indices of summation.  Good luck!  This comment will self-destruct in $15$ hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-D convolution
x(t) * h(t) = Summation x(r)h(t-r)dr
            let t-r =s
            = - Inverse Summation x(t-s)h(s)ds
            = Summation x(t-s)h(s)ds
            = h(t)*x(t)
2-D convolution

f(m,n)∗g(m−r,n−s)=Summation Summationf(h,b)g(m-r-h,n-s-b)
Let m-r-h = e
    n-s-b = c
                 = Summation Summation f(m-r-e,n-s-c)g(h,b)
                 = f(m−r,n−s)∗g(m,n)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above comment:

Show that the 2D Z-transforms of both sides are equal.

Step-by-step: If $F(z_1, z_2)$ is the 2D Z-transform of $f(m,n)$, then what is the 2D Z-transform of

1. $f(m-r, n)$?
2. $f(m-r, n-s)$?
3. $f(m, n) * g(m, n)$?
4. $f(m-r, n-s) * g(m, n)$?

(Yes, I realize that the 2D Z-transform may not be taught before this exam was presented, but it is a valid solution, nonetheless.)